# Where not exists query error

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find where the error is in this query. It's my first time using the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` syntax. Can someone help me identify what I did wrong? To me this seems ok..

```
INSERT INTO mojo (mojo_id, account_id) VALUES (35, 1) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT points_id FROM mojo 
WHERE mojo_id = 35 AND account_id = 1 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with this query?  That syntax is very wrong.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Isnt it wise to paste the error?

Comment: Oops, that was not a duplicate.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you are *really* trying to do here. As it stands, this is a candidate for an X-Y Problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tip: If you want the combination of mojo_id and account_id to be unique. Try to set a unique index on those fields in MySql. Then, alter the query to:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mojo (mojo_id, account_id) VALUES (35, 1)
```

The IGNORE statement will skip the insert when the mojo_id and account_id index already exists.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do - this would be better than subquery...lets see if it works

Comment: Hmmmm, still seems to create duplicate records unfortunately. I have a primary key in there called id...

Comment: And you set a unique index on the combination of columns mojo_id AND account_id?

Comment: For the sake of easy googling, the term is "compound index" or "composite index".

Comment: table has 3 indexes: id (primary), mojo_id, account_id - I need mojo_id and account_id to never be the same

Comment: If you don't know what I mean, you can use this query to add the index "alter table mojo add unique index(mojo_id, account_id);". Joe Frambach, you are right! Sorry ;).

Comment: Problem is that I don't want individual uniques - I need pair to be unique...

Comment: Benz's upvoted comment will do that. :) Hopefully it will become a more highly upvoted comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `values` instead of `select`:

```
INSERT INTO mojo (mojo_id, account_id) 
    select 35, 1
    from (select 1 as v) OneRow
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT points_id
                      FROM mojo 
                      WHERE mojo_id = 35 AND account_id = 1
                     ) ;
```

The `from` clause is because MySQL requires a `from` clause to use `where`.

I removed the `limit 1`s, because these were doing nothing.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting...I can learn a lot from this stuff :)